# Hide a table row if variable value is empty in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html snippet.

```
<tr>
   <td>Candidate: ${candidate1}</td>
   <td>
      <div class="radio"><label><input name="confidence_level" required="" type="radio" value="highly confident" />Highly Confident </label></div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="radio"><label><input name="confidence_level" required="" type="radio" value="moderately confident" />Moderately Confident </label></div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="radio"><label><input name="confidence_level" required="" type="radio" value="not confident" />Not Confident </label></div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I don't want to show the table row (`<tr>`) if variable `${candidate1}` is empty.

I am creating a survey in Amazon Mechanical Turk. I can use JavaScript but not jQuery. I am not familiar with JavaScript at all.

Note. I have followed this [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/RequesterUI/CreatingaHITTemplate.html) to create the survey. Please have a look at the guide in case you want to know what platform or framework AMT uses.

Comment: Why are you not using if condition before <tr>?
Which templating library you are using?

Comment: as I mentioned, I am creating a survey at AMT. I am not good in html as well. I followed this guide - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/RequesterUI/CreatingaHITTemplate.html

Comment: is `${candidate1}` from a language like PHP? or this is `jQueryTemplate`?

Comment: Perhaps it's `JQueryTemplate`, Do you try `{{if candidate1 == ''}}` at the starting of `<tr>` (at ending `</tr>` must write `{{/if}}`)?

Comment: @MortezaAsadi should I put the if condition inside the tr tag? can you give me the modified code? I tried to add the if condition outside tr tag but it doesn't work.

Comment: @WasiAhmad - Can you tell us which language or templating are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is `jQueryTemplate`, this code may help:

```
{{if candidate1 != ''}}
<tr>
   <td>Candidate: ${candidate1}</td>
   <td>
      <div class="radio"><label><input name="confidence_level" required="" type="radio" value="highly confident" />Highly Confident </label></div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="radio"><label><input name="confidence_level" required="" type="radio" value="moderately confident" />Moderately Confident </label></div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="radio"><label><input name="confidence_level" required="" type="radio" value="not confident" />Not Confident </label></div>
   </td>
</tr>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: `{{if candidate1 == ''}}` should be `{{if candidate1 != ''}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using Jquery:

```js
$('.candidate span:empty').parent().parent().hide();
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="candidate">
    Candidate: <span>${candidate1}</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
  <input name="confidence_level" required="" type="radio" value="highly confident" />Highly Confident 
  </label>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
    <input name="confidence_level" required="" type="radio" value="moderately confident" />Moderately Confident 
    </label>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
    <input name="confidence_level" required="" type="radio" value="not confident" />Not Confident 
    </label>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```